# TabPage Emptied upon inserting new Tab

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I put together some code to add a new tab in a Winforms application. The new tab is inserted but my page is now blank. I tried using the refresh command but I cant seem to come further.

```
  private void tabControl1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
  {
     var lastIndex = this.tabControl1.TabCount - 1;
     Point mouseDownLocation = new Point(e.X, e.Y);

   if(this.tabControl1.GetTabRect(lastIndex).Contains(mouseDownLocation))
   {
       this.tabControl1.TabPages.Insert(lastIndex, tabPage2);
       this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex = lastIndex;
       tabControl1.Refresh();
   }
 }
```

PIC1: [table before new tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVsL7.png)
PIC2: [table vanishes after new tab is added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xH6t.png)

Comment: If you select the first "Historie" tab, does your table appear again ? If you add an empty tab it's quite normal that it's empty... Maybe you could post a little more code so that we can see what you're doing ?

Comment: You cannot duplicate a control this way. If you you set `tabPage2.Visible = True;` after `this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex = lastIndex;` (`Refresh()` is not needed), you'll see it again. It won't last. As soon as you select the previous `tabPage2` Label, it will disappear. The `TabControl` sets `[CurrentTabPage].Visible = false;` when you switch to another tab. Since both the old and the new tab have a reference to **the same TabPage**, that page is always invisible. But, as already described, it's **the same control**. Build a TabPage template if you want to create identical controls.

Comment: @Jimi I get it. Thanks. This was not properly researched on my side.